# Bind new variables to __data__, keep existing variables

Tags: d3.js

I have `(x,y)` data bound to a couple of circles as follows:

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 640)
    .attr("height", 400)

var data = [{x: 100, y: 100}, {x: 200, y: 200}]

var circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 20)
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
```

I now want to bind a new variable `z` to each circle, using a simple [index join](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/#key).

```
newdata = [{z: 10}, {z: 30}]
circles.data(newdata)
```

If I now do `circles.data()` I see that the `z` variables have been bound as expected, but that `x` and `y` are no longer there.

Is there a way to have `x`, `y` AND `z` bound to the circles' data?

*Note that the title of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518186/manipulate-elements-by-binding-new-data) makes it sound similar, but it's not asking the same thing!*

Comment: Add `z` to the data you have, then rebind the data with the additional attribute.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done fairly easily with the [`selection.each`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#each) function:

```
// Add a new variable, 'z', equal 2 * x
circles.each(function(d) { d.z = d.x * 2; });
```

Or, for the specific case where the new data to be bound is stored in a list of objects called `newdata` (using simple indexing to join the data):

```
circles.each(function(d, i) { d.z = newdata[i].z; });
```